When transfoming an intertia tensor from one set of principle axes to another, why does it not change the tensor?
I have two inertia tensors for a cube, $I_1$ and $I_2$ where $I_1$ is the inertia tensor centered at the cube center with the axes perpendicular to the cube faces, and $I_2$ is also centered at the cube center but a $45°$ rotation about the Z axis has made the X and Y axes now point perpendicular to the edges. I have calculated both tensors by integration already. I am confused when I attempt to perform a coordinate rotation on $I_1$ using $\mathbf R$ as the rotation matrix for a rotation about the Z axis where theta is $45°$ and $I_2 = \mathbf R I_1 \mathbf R^T$ because I end up with $I_1$ again instead of a transformed inertia tensor.  Is this a quirk of rotations when both tensors are principle axes or something else?
Additionally, I am even more confused because it seems that $I_{2xx}$ and $I_{2yy}$ are both $3I_{1xx}$, as calculated by integration, which I don't see how this transformation makes that possible in the first place.

Probably a quirk of symmetry here

The inertia tensor of a cube with edge length a is
$$\mathbf I_1=\frac M6\,a^2\,\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
 $$
with arbitrary rotation angle $~\psi~$ about the z-axis you obtain
$$\mathbf I_2= \mathbf R\,\mathbf I_1\,\mathbf R^T=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \psi \right) &-\sin \left(
\psi \right) &0\\\sin \left( \psi \right) &\cos
 \left( \psi \right) &0\\0&0&1\end {array} \right]\,\frac M6\,a^2\,\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\, \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \psi \right) &-\sin \left(
\psi \right) &0\\\sin \left( \psi \right) &\cos
 \left( \psi \right) &0\\0&0&1\end {array} \right]^T$$
$$\mathbf I_2=\frac M6\,a^2\,\begin{bmatrix}
  \sin^2(\psi)+\cos^2(\psi) & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & \sin^2(\psi)+\cos^2(\psi) & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf I_1$$
this is because the cube is rotation symmetric and $~I_{xx}=I_{yy}=I_{zz}~$
Notice: not only rotation about the z axis,  also the rotation about x or y axis ,the inertia tensor before and after the transformation are equal

This answer is indeed complete after the first equation. Any constant multiple of the identity is obviously invariant under  rotations.

@paulina yes and because $~R,R^T~$ is the unity matrix

I also get the same result.
I took the formula for the moment of inertia for a solid cuboid:
$${\displaystyle I={\begin{bmatrix}{\frac {1}{12}}m(h^{2}+d^{2})&0&0\\0&{\frac {1}{12}}m(w^{2}+h^{2})&0\\0&0&{\frac {1}{12}}m(w^{2}+d^{2})\end{bmatrix}}}$$
and I said $h=d=w$ because it is a cube and the mass $m$ I just put that to be equal to $1$.
Than the inertia tensor is just $I_1=\frac{1}{6}\delta_{ij}$ and the calculation is as follows.
Given the inertia tensor $ I_1 $ and the rotation matrix  $\mathbf R$ :
$
I_1 = \frac{1}{6} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$
Rotation matrix $ \mathbf R$ for a $45°$ rotation about the Z-axis:
$
\mathbf R = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$
Calculate $ I_2 = \mathbf R I_1 \mathbf R^T $:
$
R I_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \frac{1}{6} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
= \frac{1}{6\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$
$$
I_2 = \frac{1}{6\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Simplifying:
$$
I_2 = \frac{1}{6\sqrt{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix}
= \frac{1}{12} \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{6} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
= I_1
$$
But I am not sure why either. Maybe because the principal moments of inertia are also eigenvectors and they are invariant under a linear transformation.

Not only a 45° rotation yields the same MMOI, but also any rotation $\varphi$.
Given a general rectangular prism of size $\Delta x$, $\Delta y$, $\Delta z$ has MMOI about the inertial frame after a rotation $\varphi$ about z given by the following matrix
$$\small {\rm I}_{\rm world} = m \begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{ \Delta x^2 + \Delta z^2}{12} + \frac{ (\Delta y^2-\Delta x^2) \cos^2 \varphi}{12} & \frac{(\Delta y^2-\Delta x^2)\sin\varphi\cos\varphi}{12} & \\ \frac{(\Delta y^2-\Delta x^2)\sin\varphi\cos\varphi}{12} & \frac{ \Delta y^2 + \Delta z^2}{12} + \frac{ (\Delta x^2-\Delta y^2) \cos^2 \varphi}{12} & \\  & & \frac{ \Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2}{12}  \end{bmatrix} $$
But introduce symmetry about the rotation axis with  $\Delta x = \Delta y = a$ and $\Delta z = \ell$ then
$$ {\rm I}_{\rm world} = m \begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{ a^2 + \ell^2}{12}  &  & \\  & \frac{ a^2 + \ell^2}{12}  & \\  & & \frac{ a^2 }{6}  \end{bmatrix} $$
which eliminates the rotation angle $\varphi$.
Note that a cylinder of diameter $d$ has a very similar MMOI
$$ {\rm I}_{\rm world} = m \begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\ell^2}{12}+\frac{d^2}{16}  &  & \\  & \frac{\ell^2}{12} +\frac{d^2}{16} & \\  & & \frac{ d^2 }{8}  \end{bmatrix} $$
To make all the entries the same, the extruded square must be a cube with $\ell = a$, and for a cylinder $\ell = \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} d$.

I see, I understand now from your proof why the rotation doesn't affect the inertia tensor, thank you. I still am unclear why I am able to calculate a different inertia tensor by taking the volume integral over the new bounds with the 45 degree rotation.  From your proof and my expectation originally, I would assume the tensor to be unchanged, but I instead find Ixx=Iyy= (ma^2)/2 rather than (ma^2)/6.

@JohnSmith it's very much likely you've made an error in integration then, but you didn't show us the steps so we couldn't comment on them unfortunately.
